# Analysing rotating Disc objects

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to measure the distance between a disc object (lower) and its reflection (upper) from Images, taken with a slow motion camera.

The object is a square disc and is moved by an electromagnetic field. I have Input Images, which I try to improve to help determine the distance between objects.

Folders with Images:

Input Folder - https://ufile.io/obb05

Output Folder - https://ufile.io/wjd7z

Example of input images:

[image][image][image][image][image]

Example of the improved images (with blurr filter):

[image][image][image][image][image]

Do you have an idea for a good approach to this? I thought about putting a representative geometry into the object and measure its distance to the reflection but the object quality is very inconsistent in the images, because of how the light is thrown back at the camera.

What I am trying to do is something like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

This should be difficult with these ones though:

[image]

Comment: Watershed may be useful for isolating objects.  And erosion may be used to separate them, if you know the scale.  Sorry, I'm not sure this problem is well enough specified to come up with any very specific solution.

Comment: I may be getting the wrong idea, but isn't a post like this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849536/drawing-the-longest-line-segment-contained-in-an-area